# Debugging with ADB reduces available storage each time the app is uploaded

Tags: android, adb

I 've a large app to deploy, and each time it is uploaded with adb and installed, the device storage reduces, until at some point I get an "insufficient storage error".

I assume that adb temporarily stores the APK somewhere and lots of APKs are contained in that directory. But which directory is that so I can clean it?

M.

Answer (score 0):

It may change depending on your IDE, but if you use IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio the APKs should be at `/data/local/tmp/`.

Comment: Eclipse, and there is nothing related to APKs at that location.

Comment: I'm at work, and this machine doesn't have Eclipse installed so I can't check it for you, but you should see if Eclipse logs the push of the APK when you run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this: eclipse pushes it to /data/local/tmp/ as well and uses `pm install -r` to replace if exists. I also checked on my phone and I don't have duplicates, so it might just be your app. Do you use version control?

Comment: Hmmm it's an OpenCV app statically linked. Is there a possibility that it re-generates stuff each time it's installed?